# INVALID_SKU in Amazon in-app-purchase Version 2

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, amazon-in-app-purchase

I am working on implementing subscription using Amazon IAP version 2. I am referring to the sample subscription application provided by them, for implementation.

Currently I am testing in Sandbox environment. For this I have set up

1. Amazon App tester in my device.
2. placed amazon.sdktester.json file in "mnt/sdcard" directory.

When I make a purchase request, I send child sku in the request as shown in sample. The request status I get in response is SUCCESSFUL. After receipt verification at backend server when I try to grant the subscription purchase, I get INVALID_SKU. When I print the value of SKU, it gives me Parent SKU. And in this case I have to call

```
PurchasingService.notifyFulfillment(receipt.getReceiptId(),
                    FulfillmentResult.UNAVAILABLE);
```

**UPDATE:**

My SKU at Amazon developer portal, the json I am using for testing, and in my code is same.

Could anyone please explain what exactly is going on here? Why the SKU is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

What is your SKU set in [Amazon developer portal](https://developer.amazon.com/home.html)? The SKU should be the same as the SKU in your `amazon.sdktester.json`

And, don't forget to install the `App Tester`

reference: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/testing-iap-2.0

Comment: In my question I have mentioned that I am testing in sandbox environment, also installed amazon app tester from amazon app store.

Comment: Do you also have `Amazon Test Client` on your device? According to <a href="https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs-v2/migrate-iapv1-apps-to-iapv2">this</a>, purchase will be blocked

Comment: Yes, however earlier I had different test client for version 1, later when I migrated to Version 2, i uninstalled the test client for version 1 and installed a different test client meant for Version 2 testing.